# Proving that T(A) = AB - BA is a linear transformation from V to V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove that $T(A) = AB - BA$ for $A \in V$ where $V$ is the vector space of all $n\times n$ matrixes is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V.$

First of all, I demonstrated that $T(A)$ is actually a linear transformation. After doing that I asked myself the question: okay, but that is map from V to V? For that reason I try to find the null space, since it might not map from V to V, but from V to a subspace of V. Then, the null-space is formed by the A matrixes where $AB = BA$. I don't know exactly then how to find a base of that null-space. Is it formed by all the vectors of the original basis which are a linear combination of the matrixes of the original standard basis where there are elements in the diagonal?

Comment: It in incorrect to say that $T$ is *not* a map $V\to V$ just because the range of $T$ is not all of $V.$

Comment: For example you could have a map $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by $f(x)=x $ but you could also view this as a map into $\mathbb{C} $ as $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C} $. In the case of linear maps the image will only be a linear subspace of the codomain.

Answer (score 2):

Every map from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ which turns out to be a subset of a set $Z$ is *also* a map from $X$ into $Z$.

In your case, $T$ is *not* surjective, since every matrix from the range of $T$ has null trace. Therefore, $T$ is *not* a map from $V$ *onto* $V$. But it's still a map from $V$ *into* $V$.

Comment: Okay, I think that I still need to study more about linear transformations, because there are some concepts that, although familiar, I haven't studied completely yet.

Comment: @pdaranda661: Note that this is terminology about _maps_ in general. It's not particular to those maps that happen to be linear transformations.